# rails routing difference between v3 and V5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have to migrate a Rails app from 3.0.6 to 5.0 and am stuck - in the older routes.rb the only route was the ill advised:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

The application has no index method but does use an index.html.erb that puts up a form that renders to:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="simple/rslts" controller="simple"     method="post">
```

This executes a rslts method that uses rslts.html.erb and works using parameters passed in from the form.

I move this exact same code to the v5 system and specify the routes as:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern       Controller#Action
simple GET  /simple(.:format) simple#index
       POST /simple(.:format) simple#rslts
  root GET  /                 welcome#index"
```

It runs the index.html.erb and I get this in the rendered form:

```
<form controller="simple" action="simple/rslts" accept-charset="UTF-8"    method="post">
```

It fails saying it can't find a route for /simple/simple/rslts

I change the code and now render:

```
<form controller="simple" action="rslts" accept-charset="UTF-8"     method="post">
```

It fails saying it can't find a route for /simple/rslts but as you can see from the routes I listed that does exist.

I have munged this around a dozen ways and read the routing guide with no enlightenment. This is only controllers and views, nothing else. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Re: `/simple/simple/rslts`: Your `action` attribute is just "simple/rslts" which is relative to the current URL. You'll need to prepend a slash, e.g. `action="/simple/rslts"`.
2. The route /simple/rslts is *not* defined according to your rake routes output: the right-hand side that says `simple#rslts` is the controller and action name, not part of the URL (which is on the left and has an optional format specifier). Instead you have defined that `POST /simple` should direct to the `rslts` action. You'll need to add a route for `/simple/rslts` or change the action (again) to post directly to `/simple`.

`post '/simple/rslts' => 'simple#rslts'`

Comment: Thank you Owen. Your explanation worked to get the page called. Now I'm on to the next problem. I've lost the session for the POST. I wish the Rake Routes from the V3 system would show me the actual routes. At least I'm understanding more about this.

Comment: Actually if that was the only route in the Rails 3 codebase it should be easy, e.g. ```/simple/rslts``` is SimpleController#rslts, ```/payments/remit``` is PaymentsController#remit, etc.